# Is Vitess supports sequence(auto-increment) only in unsharded keyspaces?

Tags: mysql, sharding, vitess, kubernetes-vitess

As documentation says, it should be first creating backing table, so it confused what it should be

Comment: Please state your goal; maybe it is achievable some other way.  There are other ways to produce "unique" numbers across multiple servers; describe your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The docs describe how sequences are implemented. Vitess needs a one-row table that keeps the state of the sequence. *That* state table needs to be un-sharded.

The sequence values themselves can be used in a sharded table.

Looking at the docs: https://vitess.io/docs/18.0/reference/features/vitess-sequences/
`user_seq` is a un-sharded table, `user` is a sharded table that utilises the sequence for auto-increment.